# Making a Rollback Class - Ruby

Tags: ruby, transactions, rollback

i'm in need to create a class that acts as rollbacker.

```
class Rollbacker
def perform(*args, &block)
  begin
    objCopy, @originalState = args

    objCopy.each do |i|
      i.instance_eval(&block)
    end
  rescue
    objCopy = @originalState //Here i tried also with args = originalState
    raise
  end
end
```

The issue i'm having is that "perform" works fine (the block executes fine with args), but when rescue happens (and the error is raised), i need that args returns too it's original state without the changes of the "begin" but is not happening.

If i'm not mistaken, in the "begin" i'm working on a copy of args and then changing it in rescue, but don't know why is not working

Any thoughts on what to change?

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages the all-lowercase with underscores style for naming variables and method names, so `objCopy` should be `obj_copy`. This is because capital letters are used to signify constants like `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: How are you using this code? The way it's employed is not entirely clear. If you could put together two simple examples, one that throws an exception and one that doesn't, it'd be easier to explain what's wrong.

Comment: if you're mutating `args` then use `clone` to preserve it and use _that_ in the rescue block.

Answer (score -1):

An example would be, having a class Klass:

```
class Klass
attr_accessor :counter

def initialize(c)
  @counter= c
end

def plus
  self.counter = self.counter+ 1
end
end
---------------------------  

rollbacker.perform(Klass.new(0)) {|k| k.plus} //this leaves the counter in 1. Currently working fine

---------------------------
k = Klass.new(0)
def kaboom(k)
  tr.perform(k) {|k|
    k.plus
    raise 'Kaboom!'}
end                    //This should raise the error (which it does), but the counter should stay on 0; but at the moment it stays in 1 (the plus happens, but not rollback is happening)
```

Comment: Edit your question to add this detail. This is not an answer.